# XMLHttpRequest for receiving Server Sent Events (SSE) is only working after browser page is opened

Tags: javascript, react-native, xmlhttprequest, server-sent-events

In our react native app we are using binaryminds [react-native-sse](https://github.com/binaryminds/react-native-sse) library for receiving Server Sent Events (SSE). In our case we are using it for receiving notifications sent by the backend. The library internally uses XHR for polling our webflux stream endpoint.

But it is not working. The onreadystatechange callback (which should dispatch the message event) is not being called although the SSE's are being sent by the server. The backend is recognizing the subscriber and also sents the notifications, they are just not being received.

After some trial we figured out that when a browser page is opened in the app **before** the XMLHttpRequest is opened, then the SSE's are suddenly arriving and everything works fine. We use

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'
Linking.openURL(someURL)
```

to open the browser in-app

So my question would be: **Does opening a browser in a react native app somehow changes the implementation of the XMLHttpRequest or what is happening here?**

We are using Expo for building the App